# I can not find virtualization technology is bios to enable it i want to use virtualmachine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I own a toshiba satellite c55d-a with amd a4 apu 5000 cpu
Im entering bios settings by pressing f2 key when booting but I'm unable to find virtualization option there

Comment: Your machine may not have the option - some machines do not.  Look in all the BIOS settings also for VT-D .  You may need to open some sections.

Comment: I opened all the sections and can't find any thing related is there any way to run the virtual machine

Comment: Without VT-D you can only run 32-bit guests, not 64-bit guests.

Comment: How to know if my laptop supports virtualization or not

Comment: VMware (at least) will install, just run 32-bit only.

Comment: contact support, and ask if they have a firmware flash that enables it. the CPU, Motherboard, and firmware must all support the VT extensions, so right now its unclear whether the hardware is capable but the firmware locks out the option, or if it is just not supported by the hardware.

Comment: In my task manager it appears that virtualization is disabled that means that the device supports it but the issue is how to enable it

Comment: @John - VT-d isn’t hardware Virtualization your think of VT-x; VT-d is  Directed I/O and isn’t required to run a 64-bit VM.

Comment: @michel - Your conclusion that if it’s disabled it can be enabled isn’t accurate; furthermore VT-d is Intel only, likewise VT-x is also Intel only; AMD hardware has its own versions.

Comment: While your APU supports AMD-V your motherboard firmware must provide the option to enable it.  If that option does not exist it cannot be enabled.  If you cannot find the option then it doesn’t exist.

Comment: @ramhound- i mean that if the device does not support virtualization then it will not appear as disable in my task manager

Comment: After searching the internetz for the specific problem you are having.. it looks like MANY (if not ALL) laptops that used this exact chip did not provide a method to enable virtualization.  Acer, Toshiba, Gateway.. I have to wonder if the technology was fully cooked in this chipset.  There has to be some reason that so many OEMs didn't implement it.

Comment: Plua when I searched for my processor on the internet it seems like virtualization is supported

Comment: And yes sir.. we all see that it SHOULD be supported.. buy you aren't the only one complaining that there is no UEFI firmware support to turn it on.. and that appears to be VERY common with the OEMS that used this chip.

Comment: My use of "VT-"  was just a typo (going from memory) . There should be words like  "vritualization"  and 'VT- something"  in your BIOS setup if your machine with current BIOS supports virtualization.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: So from farther back here, you can only run 32-bit guests VMware Workstation should install.

Comment: @michel - Your APU does support AMD-V but that doesn’t mean you can enable it.  If you cannot enable it then there isn’t anything you can do.  There isn’t anything preventing you from running a 32-bit VM